# Есть ли у функции register_shutdown_function() ограничения?

Tags: php

Есть ли у функции register_shutdown_function() ограничения на то какие действия они будет выполнять? Например у меня даже такой простой код не выполняется - не пишется в файл. Так же как не отправляется email

```
    <?php
function fatal_error_handler()
{
file_put_contents('error.log', '1');
}
register_shutdown_function('fatal_error_handler');
```

Answer (score 1):

Нашел на английской версии stackoverflow:

> In case anybody else runs into this problem: The issue was caused by the shutdown function being called from a different context in which the execution directory was different from the normal /www directory. The solution was to add a chdir('xxx') before the call to mail() to change back to the www directory.

Суть в том что текущий каталог изменяется, поэтому надо заходить в корневой каталог через chdir()